# Finding Ratio of Every Column Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Let's say I have the following DF.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
    [('a',0, 1,1), ('b',1, 3,4), ('c',2, 5,7)]), ('acc_no','col_1', 'col_2','sum'))

+------+-----+-----+---+
|acc_no|col_1|col_2|sum|
+------+-----+-----+---+
|     a|    0|    1|  1|
|     b|    1|    3|  4|
|     c|    2|    5|  7|
+------+-----+-----+---+
```

I want to find the create a new column for percentage of **col_1** and **col_2** over the **sum** column as below.

```
+------+-----+-----+---+---------+---------+
|acc_no|col_1|col_2|sum|perc_col1|perc_col2|
+------+-----+-----+---+---------+---------+
|     a|    0|    1|  1|        0|      100|
|     b|    1|    3|  4|       25|       75|
|     c|    2|    5|  7|       29|       71|
+------+-----+-----+---+---------+---------+
```

I know I can use the following code to add the percentage column for each col_1 and col_2

```
df.withColumn('perc_col1',col('col_1')/col('sum')*100).withColumn('perc_col2',col('col_2')/col('sum')*100).show()
```

But how can I do it if I have **hundreds** of columns and I'd like to avoid writing hundreds lines of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `withcolumn`, you can use a for loop with `df.select` in this case and rename using `.alias` and `f-strings`

```
col_list = ['col_1','col_2'] #list of multiple columns
out = df.select("*",*[F.round((F.col(i)/F.col("sum"))*100,2).alias(f"perc_{i}")
                      for i in col_list])
```

---

```
out.show()
+------+-----+-----+---+----------+----------+
|acc_no|col_1|col_2|sum|perc_col_1|perc_col_2|
+------+-----+-----+---+----------+----------+
|     a|    0|    1|  1|       0.0|     100.0|
|     b|    1|    3|  4|      25.0|      75.0|
|     c|    2|    5|  7|     28.57|     71.43|
+------+-----+-----+---+----------+----------+
```

---

Or loop with withcolumn:

```
col_list = ['col_1','col_2']
for i in col_list:
    df = df.withColumn(f"perc_{i}",F.round((F.col(i)/F.col("sum"))*100,2))
df.show()
```

Comment: good stuff man, like it